# Invalid Warning in foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, web

I am new to php and been taking a php programing class this summer semester and i was wondering if someone can help me figure what i need to do in order for things to work.

I am working on a final project and we had to build our on little database on the subject that we wanted. So I choose to do a movie database. And I had used some code already from my_guitar_shop from murach's php book. which is the Murach's php and mysql book. And for some reason when I go to index.php page, I can not get my information to show up in my table on my page.

I will show you the  code for my index page

```
<?php
require_once('database.php');
if (isset($_POST['deleteThis'])) {
    $deleteThis = $_POST['deleteThis'];
    $sqlDel="DELETE FROM categories WHERE categoryID = $deleteThis";
    $temp=$db->exec($sqlDel);

}


// Get all categories
$query = 'SELECT * FROM categories
ORDER BY categoryID';
$categories = $db->query($query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<!-- the head section -->
<head>
<title>My Movie Store</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<!-- the body section -->
<body>
    <center>
        <div id="heading">My Movie Store</div>
    </center>

    <div id="page">

        <div id="header">
            <h1>Top Movies</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="main">

            <h1>Movie List</h1>
            <table class="content">
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>

                <?php foreach($categories as $cat) {
                    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $cat['categoryName'];?>
                    </td>

                    <form method="post" action="category_list.php">
                        <input type="hidden" name="deleteThis"
                            value="<?php echo $cat['categoryID']; ?> " />
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                        </td>
                    </form>

                    <?php
                }
                ?>

            </table>
            <br />

            <h2>Add a Movie</h2>

            <!-- add code for the form here -->

            <p>
                <a href="add_product_form.php">Add Movie</a>
            </p>

            <br />
            <p>
                <a href="index.php">Movie List</a>
            </p>

        </div>
        <!-- end main -->

        <div id="footer">
            <p>
                &copy;
                <?php echo date("2012"); ?>
                My Movie Store, created by Kara Holey
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- end page -->
</body>
</html>
```

My database name is called moviedatabase that i had created in localhost/phpmyadmin and my 2 tables underneath the database are called categories and movies. and for some reason thsi is the error that i get on this page.

*Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\1306\finalp\index.php on line 82*

If anyone can help me that would be great.

Comment: Stop guessing and see what **actually** in `categories` using `var_dump($categories);`. And never rely on what you think is in variable - **always** check it with `var_dump()`

Comment: If its PDO you need to fetch the result `$db->query($query)->fetchAll()` also change `date("2012");` to `date("Y");` ;p

Comment: That error means that `$categories` is not an array (it's probably empty). Start with your db connection and make sure you're connecting properly.

Comment: In the future, you might add something like "###### ERROR REPORTED ON THIS LINE" to your code.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone nay, `PDOStatement` is a traversable, so it can be used in a foreach

Answer (score 0):

Your variable $categories in `foreach` loop isn't a valid collection that's why php gives you this error. You need to see what `$categories` really is.

I doubt it might be a resource returned from your query or could be a null.

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = $db->query($query) // this is your problem
```

I think your `foreach()` is not receiving a valid array. Try troubleshooting with a static array you create!!

example make

```
$categories = array("A","B");
foreach($categories as $value){
   echo $value."<br/>";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PDO, this probably means your query failed and the output of `$db->query()` is `false`.

To avoid this problem, I would suggest enabling exception handling:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

You can add this to `database.php`. Doing this will produce a very obvious and hard-to-miss exception if a query fails with details as to why it failed.